# What distribution have these 3 taskbar tweaks possible?

Tags: taskbar

I need information if it's possible to configure these 3 things in KDE (Kubuntu 18.04) or any other distro:

1. When I move mouse cursor over taskbar I'd like to automatically activate and move to front the window of application the cursor is currently over.
2. Always use the full space of taskbar. So, when I open only 1 application I'd like it to fill the whole taskbar. When I'll open N windows I'd like it to divide whole taskbar with N equal parts.
3. Add "global" button on the taskbar that will close (maybe also maximize and minimize) currently active window.

I currently use XFCE with points 2 and 3 configured successfully. I used this kind of configuration in Fluxbox few years ago, but it's just too simplistic in other subjects as you know. Is it possible in KDE or Lubuntu? Do you know any other environment that can be configured like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try LiveCD/USB of [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) to test will it suite your needs or not.

I'm very happy with MATE's methods of window manipulation (in particular with many plots from Scilab and/or Octave and so on):

- MATE DE with multiple windows of the same application:

  [image: 5 Octave windows and two other windows]

if it is not enough you can use *Window Picker* applet (shown on top panel):

- *Window Picker* applet in action

  [image: Window Picker in action]

or use *Window Selector* applet (shown on top panel) as drop-down menu or with mouse wheel -

- *Windows Selector* applet in action

  [image: Window Selector in action]

if you want to use modern dock - then you can utilize *Mutiny* panel layout (selectable from MATE Tweak):

- *Mutiny* panel layout

  [image: Mutiny panel layout]

For me this functionality is well enough.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Ubuntu MATE. It offers no options like I described.