# Ubuntu Mate 18.04 applets alternatives, window picker

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

I usually have a lot of open applications, and I want to find a window picker alternative.  Where would I go to find these alternatives?

For example, for KDE I would go to https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/105/ and find what I need there.

Is there an equivalent website I can go for applets compatible with Mate?

```
$ wmctrl -m                                                               
Name: Metacity (Marco)
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

Comment: Doesn't Mate include *rofi*? While it's not an "applet", it allows you to list, switch between, and close windows pretty handily.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1098722/66509 as it may be useful for your case.